How to solve login error in flutter app with php API
I worked on login in flutter app with API and the opreation done very successfully but when I add fetch data for client to take id and name and transfer between pages happend error socket expectation.
     include_once "database.php";
    include_once "cores.php";

    $phone = $_POST['phone'];

    $select = "SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE `phone`='$phone' AND `status`='Active' ";
    $run = mysqli_query($connect, $select);


    if (mysqli_num_rows($run) > 0) 
    {
        $userData = array();

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run))
        {
            $userData = $row;
        }


        echo json_encode(
            array(
                "check" => true, 
                "userID" => $userData[0]
            )
        );

    } 
    else 
    {
        echo json_encode(array("check" => false));
    }

and flutter
  Future<void> LoginClient() async
  {

    if (phone.text.isNotEmpty) 
    {
      try 
      {

        var validate = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(ApisConnect.checkPhoneNumberApi),
          body: {
            "phone" : phone.text
          }
        );

        var response1 = jsonDecode(validate.body);

        if (response1["exists"] == true) 
        {
          var login = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(ApisConnect.loginApi),
            body: {
              "phone": phone.text,
            },
          );

          var response2 = jsonDecode(login.body);

          if (response2["check"] == true) 
          {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DashboardScreen()));

            User userInfo = User.fromJson(response2["userID"]);
            
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Logined Successfully,'); 
          }
          else if(response2['check'] == false)
          {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'You Are blocked, If you have any error call Techneical Support');
          }

        }
        else
        {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'This Number not signed, sign up first.');
        }

      } 
      catch (e) 
      {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Error: $e');
      }       
    }
    else
    {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Fill The field first');
    }

be careful the error happend when I add userID in php before add user line in flutter and after add the error still found

Since you use mysqli_fetch_assoc the result from the SQL operation will be an associative array. So $userData[0] will not work, you need to use the column names in your database.
For example if the user id in client table is userId, the correct way to get it is:
$userData["userId"]

I assume $connect is comming from one of the included files, you might need global $connect; after to include_once statements.
Besides your current code is dangerously open to SQL injection, please consider using prepared statements every time your SQL command includes any user input.
